# How to redirect querystring url to subdomain url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect query string URL to subdomain URL:

`https://domainname.com/login/?_redirected=yes`
to
`http://subdomain.domain.com`.

I tried some of htaccess code but it's not working. How can i solve this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myhost.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1&preview=true)
RewriteRule ^$ http://alt.myhost.com/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is it not redirecting? Is it giving you a 500 error? Is apache configured to load .htaccess. To check put some garbage in your .htaccess file and it should 500, unless it's already 500-ing, than you need to look in your webserver error log and see what's going on.

Comment: yes it's giving 500 error how can i redirect with htaccess.

Comment: Give me any suggestion please.

Comment: Did you check the average things like rewrite engine is on and if mod rewrite is enabled for htaccess files?

Comment: yes i checked rewrite engine is on

Comment: What does the apache error log say is the problem, if it does?

Comment: It gives RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters